# Can I see what jquery is sending to an external server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am on a website...it has jquery and is sending some requests using javascript out to a php page.

Is their any way to see what data it is sending out from my computer and/or which URLs it is talking to?

I am using firefox and can load software if their is any needed.

EDIT - I have downloaded firebug and have the page loaded.  Any idea what option I need to select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firebug, you can open the "Console" panel. Every time an AJAX request is made, you'll see either GET or POST and the URL that the request was sent to logged. You can click on the triangle beside it to expand, and then click through the various tabs to see the data sent, the response back, and other assorted information.

EDIT: The XHR tab in the "Net" panel will show you the same information as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use Firebug browser addon, it will show you background XHR requests.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to intercept all the calls to and from the browser. You can inspect the entire HTTP communication.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  It loads as a proxy between your browser in the server to see everything you would ever want to know about the request.

This is independent of the browser, so you can use it in any browser you would like.  You can even use it on mobile devices if you manually set their proxy server to be your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a second answer as it's completely different than my first one.

Since a number of people are recommending Fiddler (which is an awesome tool!), I wanted to throw out the option of using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). It's cross-platform, while Fiddler is Windows-only. Unfortunately, Charles isn't free (well, it is, you can use it without paying, but have to deal with the nagware popups all the time). It's worth paying for, though.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for this, in Firefox, is called [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)